# Select Element By CSS style (all with given style)

Tags: javascript, css, dom, css-selectors

Is there a way to select all elements that have a given style using JavaScript?

Eg, I want all absolutely positioned elements on a page.

I would assume it is easier to find elements by style where the style is explicitly declared:

- the style is non-inherited (such as positioning)
- the style is not the default (as would be position:static).

Am I limited to those rules?  Is there a better method for when those rules apply?

I would happily to use a selector engine if this is provided by one (ideally Slick - Mootools 1.3)

EDIT:
I came up with a solution that will only work with above rules.
 
It works by cycling through every style rule, and then selector on page.
Could anyone tell me if this is better that cycling through all elements (as recommended in all solutions).
I am aware that in IE I must change the style to lowercase, but that I could parse all styles at once using cssText. Left that out for simplicity.
Looking for best practice.

```
var classes = '';
Array.each(documents.stylesheets, function(sheet){
   Array.each(sheet.rules || sheet.cssRules, function(rule){
      if (rule.style.position == 'fixed') classes += rule.selectorText + ',';
   });
});
var styleEls = $$(classes).combine($$('[style*=fixed]'));
```

Comment: @samgoody Your bullet points are confusing. First one makes various assumptions, then second one seems to discard it by saying - "without making said assumptions" :)

Comment: @Anurag. You are absolutely correct. Thanks. Fixed. (I hope.  Is that better?)

Comment: Your approach seems faster, as a `css` or `getStyle` call for each element results in a call to the native `getComputedStyle` which is time-consuming. CSS rules, OTOH, are already parsed beforehand, and it's simply a matter of looping through them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Mootools:

```
var styleEls = $$('*').filter(function(item) {
    return item.getStyle('position') == 'absolute';
});
```

Comment: +1: It [works](http://jsfiddle.net/nrqhS/), is elegant and is actually in mootools - the preferred library of the asker.

Answer (score 10):

You can keep Mootools, or whatever you use... :)

```
function getStyle(el, prop) {
  var view = document.defaultView;
  if (view && view.getComputedStyle) {
    return view.getComputedStyle(el, null)[prop];
  }
  return el.currentStyle[prop];
}

​function getElementByStyle(style, value, tag)​ {
  var all = document.getElementsByTagName(tag || "*");
  var len = all.length;
  var result = [];
  for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
    if ( getStyle(all[i], style) === value )
      result.push(all[i]);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In jQuery you could use

```
$('*').filter( function(){
  return ($(this).css('position') == 'absolute');
} );
```

***[update]***

Or even create a new selector.
got me interested and so here is one (*its my 1st, so its not built for efficiency*) to find elements by css property..

```
$.expr[':'].css = function(obj, index, meta, stack){
  var params = meta[3].split(',');

  return ($(obj).css(params[0]) == params[1]);
};
```

**usage**: `$('optionalSelector:css(property,value)')`
will return all elements (*of optionalSelector*) whose property = value

**example**: `var visibleDivs = $('div:css(visibility,visible)');`
will return all divs whose visibility is set to visible (*works for the default visibility as well..*)

Answer (score -1):

There is no selector for CSS attributes, so you're pretty much stuck to looping through each element and checking it's position. Here's a jQuery method:

```
$("*").each(function() {
    var pos = $(this).css('position');
    if(pos == "absolute") {
        // do something
    }
    else if (pos == "relative") {
        // do something else
    }
});
```

You can use Case statements instead of if/else as well.

Other than this solution, there is no selector per se that can search by CSS attributes (unless they were inline, maybe).

Comment: I have no issue with JQuery, but you ought to specify that you are using it - I went searching to find out what that .css() function was.

Comment: @SamGoody, I guess it was more satisfying to downvote rather than adding a few words to the answer? In any event, I added those words.

Comment: @JohnK I didn't down-vote your answer (especially as it could be useful to others), just commented on it. But perhaps I should have edited the answer instead of making a comment? Not sure, I personally dislike aggressive editing as much as I dislike aggressive down-voting.

Comment: @SamGoody, okay, good to hear. FYI I added four words.