# CSS attribute selector in IE7 - Contains substring on the style attribute

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I would like to select an element on its style element. For example, my current WYSIWYG editor puts style attributes to align images, like so:

```
<img src="my_image.png" style="align: left;" />
```

Selectors I've tried:

```
img[style*='align: left']
img[style*='align:left']
img[style*='eft']
```

All these work fine in all browsers except IE7.

Comment: I had posted an answer, but then went and tested and it didn't work as I expected. So I deleted it. I know that part of the issue is the `*=` is a CSS3 selector. I thought `img[style~='align: left']` would work, but it did not when tested in a fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's not possible: according to [sitepoint](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3attributeselectors)

> In Internet Explorer 7: The style attribute can't be used in attribute
>   selectors.

so basically the only way to target that element on IE<7 is probably using javascript

Comment: You found the note about `sytle` before me :-). [There is another stack overflow that shows javascript solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260210/select-element-by-css-style-all-with-given-style/3260325#3260325) as you mention (and I mentioned in my answer here).

Answer (score 0):

Doing [a bit of research online yielded](http://www.impressivewebs.com/attribute-selectors/) the fact that IE7 does not recognize (even CSS2) attribute selection for the `style` element.

If there is a way to configure your WYSIWYG to apply a `class` to those elements being aligned (and perhaps doing the alignment by that), then IE7 will recognize `img[class~=yourClassName]` as an attribute selector. But then, it is quite likely you would just apply your style through the class itself: `img.yourClassName` and skip the whole attribute selection.

Otherwise, [use javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260210/select-element-by-css-style-all-with-given-style/3260325#3260325).